# Remove elements from QList of pointers

Tags: c++, qt4, qlist

I have a QList variable. How can I erase all the elements starting from an X index and removing all the subsequents N elements taking care of freeing also the memory?

Comment: What is "X" in your question?

Comment: X is my start index, I should be able to delete N elements starting from the row X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should never use `MyClass*` to "own" (i.e. control the lifetime of) an instance of `MyClass`. Thus, a list of `MyClass*` shouldn't "own" any instances of `MyClass`, either. Thus you wouldn't ever use the `delete` operator with any of these pointers (and a stray `delete` outside a smartpointer implementation should almost always raise a few eyebrows).

`QList` is in fact a type optimized for a similar use-case. A `QList<MyClass>` will internally store a dynamic array of `MyClass*` (if `MyClass` is larger than a pointer), so re-ordering and expanding the list is potentially cheaper. However, if you need to remove elements from the list *without* deleting them, you should use a `QList<unique_ptr<MyClass>>` or similar. Either way, you wouldn't have to worry about the objects' lifetimes; you'd only need to remove them from the list.

Now that I said that, there are a few useful STL idioms that will help achieving what you're looking for, and they also apply to (most) Qt containers (*edit: fixed the removal, added a few helpful comments*):

```
QList<MyClass*> myList; //TODO FIXME XXX: clarify mentioned ownership issues
assert(X + N <= myList.size());

// this is the range of objects we want to remove and delete
// (N elements, starting from index X)
auto range_begin = myList.begin() + X,
     range_end = range_begin + N;
// delete each object in range
std::for_each(range_begin, range_end, [](MyClass* ptr) { delete ptr; });
// remove them from the list
myList.erase(range_begin, range_end);
```

It's even simpler still, if you meant to remove all elements after `myList[X - 1]` (in short, replace `range_end` with `myList.end()`).

Comment: this seems to be less error-prone that the answer of Blood but it uses std and I would stick to Qt only. Also, the Blood solution uses only one loop while here I should use two loops, one for deleting the object and one to erase from the list the elements. However, I like more in your reply the fact that you use iterators. Is there a way to mix your answer and the Blood's one to use iterators but with one loop?

Comment: @Stefano: Yes, it does use two loops; however, the other answer really uses N loops behind the scenes! You should also note that it *doesn't* loop twice *over the same range*, because that's not how `erase` works. If you want to avoid STL (and I can't think why you should, it's 2012!), you can replace the `for_each` with a `for` loop; there's nothing inherently STL about using iterators as Qt containers support them as well.

Comment: @Stefano: Besides, there's no avoiding two loops in what you're trying to achieve. First, you got to loop over `[range_begin, range_end)` to delete the elements. Then you have to loop over *the trailing elements* to move them backwards (this is what `erase` does), and only then you can truncate the list. This isn't inefficient; it's just about as optimal as it can get.

Comment: FYI, using `QList<unique_ptr<MyClass>>` will be problematic in Qt 4.x, which doesn't support move semantics. `QList`'s implementation of `push_back` only accepts `const T&` and not `T&&`.